# Cell displays wrong number value

Tags: excel, cell, number-formatting

A1: value displays as `49.0` in cell but when clicked top bar displays `48.9847219431886`.
A2: value displays as `43.0` in cell but when clicked top bar displays `42.9792446979968`.

So If I want to use this cell value in another cell, let's say in CONCATENATE function, it concatenates wrong value.

`=Concat(A1," - " ,A2)` gives result **48.9847219431886 - 42.9792446979968**

but I want it should be **49.0 - 43.0**

I have checked the number format and it is set to 'Custom' with type `_(* #,##0.0_);_(* (#,##0.0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_).`
Tried changing format to text and number but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the formatting of each number being concatenated by writing

`=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1, "#,##0.0"), " - ", TEXT(A2, "#,##0.0"))`.

Comment: Great!! Worked just fine. But is there any way where we could just change formatting of actual cell to display the actual value in other cells.

Comment: No. You can't tie the formatting of one cell to another cell (unless you use some horrific volatile VBA functions). Another solution would be to `Round` the values in A1 and A2. But that will, of course, introduce an approximation.